# Filtering by channel

Tags: search, filter, filtering

I have a page where I am listing out all entries to all channels. I want to have a filter for filtering by channel. Anyone know how to do this with pro search (EE7)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this with pro search, but you can try setting up a filter using [dynamic parameters](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/entries.html#dynamic_parameters).

1. Create a form where a user can select a channel or channels, send his selection to your template
2. Catch POST data using `dynamic_parameters="channel"` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with Pro Search you can try out the following:

I have a template with

```
{exp:pro_search:form result_page="test/return_pro_result"}

<select name="channel" id="channel">
    {collections}
  <option value={collection_name}>{collection_name}</option>
  {/collections}
</select>
<input type="submit">   

{/exp:pro_search:form}
```

and then my return_pro_result template looks like

```
{exp:pro_search:results query="{segment_3}" limit="10"}
    {if count ==  1}<ol>{/if}
      <li><a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{title}</a></li>
    {if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
    {if no_results}No search results{/if}
{/exp:pro_search:results}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work for what I want will it? 
I want to list out all channels and filter entries by that.